# How to route traffic from on-prem via transit-gateways in same AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services, transit-gateway

We need to be able to route traffic from our on-premise servers via our Direct Connect to our transit gateway and then to our partner which also has transit gateway.

However because both TGWs are in the same region this does not allow peering. It supports VPC peering, but this I dont think works when you want to use your on-premise networks.

Any suggestions?

Here is the traffic scenario
On-prem ---> Direct Connect ---> Transit Gateway (eu-central-1) ---> Peering -----> Transit Gateway (eu-central-1) ---> ec-2

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possibly. You can peering TGW that belongs to the same region.
From documentation:
Configuration steps and requirements for intra-region Transit Gateway peering are exactly the same as for inter-region peering. You can create a ‘peering’ attachment between your Transit Gateway and another Transit Gateway in the same AWS Region. The peered Transit Gateway can be in your own AWS account or a different AWS account.

More info:
https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/aws-transit-gateway-now-supports-intra-region-peering/

Comment: great that they added support for this